# Trying to insert collection from mongodb to mysql table

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mysql-python

mongodb contains 2 collection with 5 fields each:

```
{
    "channel details": c,
    "playlist details": p,
    "video_ids": v_id,
    "video details": v,
    "comment details"
```

I am trying to push each field in a separate table in MySQL. e.g. all fields in channel details from both collection to channel details table using Python in Jupyter notebook

[mongo db with 2 collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8S6Js.png)

[in collection channel details contains these fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkBAq.png)

[mysql table for channel details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqFlN.png)

```
mydb = client["Youtubehar_DB"]
collection=mydb['youtube_data']

collection.find({},{"channel details":1,"_id":0})

df4=pd.DataFrame(collection.find({},{"channel details":1,"_id":0}))

df4

channel details
0   [{'Channel_id': 'U', 'Channel_name': 'Cone Ice...
1   [{'Channel_id': 'U', 'Channel_name': 'Vj Siddh...

sql = "INSERT INTO channel_details (channel_id, Channel_name, Playlist_id, Subscribers, Views, Total_videos, Description, Country) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"

for i in range(0,len(df4)):
    cur.execute(sql,tuple(df4.iloc[i]))
    myconnection.commit()

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, dict found
```